# addTestDevice not working

Tags: android

When I try and incorporate test ads into my app it doesn't show the ad and creates an error : ** error: non-static method addTestDevice(String) cannot be referenced from a static context** I'm not sure how to fix this so thanks in advance.

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("DF738A0CF9E96DB06B085AADFEDCF0CF");


   android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/main_screen_titletwo"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />
```

.

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxx"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT FIXED**

Didn't realise my unitid was there so I put it in.

Comment: I think you are missing parentheses in a constructor call:  `new AdRequest().Builder().build();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you are calling the `addTestDevice()` function statically on the `Builder` class instead of on an instance returned by the `Builder()` constructor

However you should do it like this:

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
         .addTestDevice("DF738A0CF9E96DB06B085AADFEDCF0CF")
         .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

because adding the test device after you have already called `build()` won't have any effect.

What this code does is create an `AdRequest.Builder` object by calling `AdRequest.Builder()`, then calls `addTestDevice()` on the object, and then calls `build()` on it to return an `AdRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `static` before the declaration of `addTestDevice(String)`

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand. Could you give me a line of code to show this please? @Mohammad Arman

Comment: Declare the method addTestDevice(String) like below:


`public static String addTestDevice(String yourParameter){
.
.
}`